# Is it possible to "skin" or "theme" an Angular2 component with CSS when using ViewEncapsulation?

Tags: css, angular

I have to make Angular2 components look completely different (not just the colors) by the click of a button. So very much like different CSS "Skins" or "Themes". It would also be nice if some "Skins" could be added later.

I know I can simply set `ViewEncapsulation.None` and do it with swappable CSS files like in the old days.
But I wonder if there is a possibility to use `ViewEncapsulation`?

Any hint is appreciated!
Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
@HostBinding('attr.theme') theme = this.globalService.theme;
```

to your components and make styles depending on the value of the class

```
   :host([theme="dark"]) {
     color: lightgrey;
     background-color: black;
   }

   :host([theme="light"]) {
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
   }
```

You can't add/remove component styles at runtime.

If you add styles to index.html then you lose style encapsulation (with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default)) but you can add/remove them at will.